# How to change html tag content

Tags: javascript, html, css

i tried changing html tag content but it not working

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('h4').innerHTML('Hi world');
```

```css
h4{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Hello world</h4>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML = 'Hi world';

Comment: Also, `getElementsByTagName(...)` returns an array. You must choose the element in the array you want to change innerHTML to (element on index 0 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You're just using the innerHTML property the wrong way.

The right method is `.innerHTML = 'Hi world';`

> Read more about innerHTML here:
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Also, don't forget to select the first index of the array as the `getElementsByTagName` function returns an array of elements

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0]
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML='Hi world';
```

```css
h4{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Hello world</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

It says "getElements" so it's PLURAL. It's a collection of elements so you need to specify which to operate on and hence the square brackets...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML='Hi world';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML = 'Hi world';
```

```css
h4{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Hello world</h4>
```